# How to solve this err: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction has an ancient birth block?

Tags: parachain

How to solve this err?

1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction has an ancient birth block

Comment: Please provide a little bit more context

Answer (score 1):

For FRAME-based runtimes this would be caused by current block number - Era::birth block number > BlockHashCount. (e.g. in Polkadot BlockHashCount = 2400, so a transaction with birth block number 1337 would be valid up until block number 1337 + 2400, after which point the transaction would be considered to have an ancient birth block.) ([ref](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b3cacfb059e9d79d1cde270c796dc0f33ff3ef20/primitives/runtime/src/transaction_validity.rs#L59-L68))